# Json, urlib2 and pprint

Tags: python, json

I have the following exercise:

*Use the [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module. First use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html) to download this file, then load the json as a python object and use **pprint** to make it look good when written to the terminal.*

Now until now I've only worked with standard Python things (such as the codeacademy course and things such as lists).

What I understand is that I have to import urllib2 and apparently import json in some other way and use pprint...???

This is what I have done, but not sure if I got it right...

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/153071/test.json')
html = response.read()
import json
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(c) #Just printing a list from earlier in the file, not sure what to print...
```

Comment: What's the result that you obtain?

Comment: Sounds pretty straight forward - urrlib2 to download the file, json to parse it, finally pprint to display it. You've already downloaded the file's content into your html variable, why aren't you parsing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to import `pprint`. You can specify indentation using the json module itself

```
import urllib2                                                                       
import json                                                                          
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/153071/test.json')   
content_dict = json.loads(response.read())                                           
print json.dumps(content_dict, indent=4)
```